# How to encode a portion of path in URI using UriComponentsBuilder?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, encode, encodeuricomponent

I have a path that looks like this: `/service/method/{id}/{parameters}` which I call using restTemplate, where `/service/method` is a microservice, `{id}` is some id that I need to ask for, and `{parameters}` is a link that looks something like this: `/home/floor/kitchen/` that I use for mapping in a JsonNodeTree later in the service/method microservice.

I am trying to use

```
    Map<String, String> uriVariables = new HashMap<String, String>();
            uriVariables.put("id", "5080572115");
            uriVariables.put("parameters", "/home/floor/kitchen/");

            UriComponents uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance().scheme("http").host("service/methods/{id}").
            path("/{parameters}").buildAndExpand(uriVariables).encode();
String finalURI = uriComponents.toUriString();
return restTemplate.getForObject(finalURI, Integer.class);
```

But what I get is the whole link http://service/methods/{id}/{parameters} encoded. And what I need is only a portion of it ({parameters}) to be encoded so I can parse the other part of the url into the RestTemplate. 
To be clear again, I need to parse service/methods/{id} into RestTemplate, and decode {parameters} later to use as a path for the JsonNodeTree.

edit: I am aware of queries but couldn’t find a solution of encoding a portion of a path.

Answer (score 3):

To get a path variable encoded, you need to use [`pathSegment(String... pathSegments)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html#pathSegment-java.lang.String...-):

```
Map<String, String> uriVariables = new HashMap<>();
uriVariables.put("id", "5080572115");
uriVariables.put("parameters", "/home/floor/kitchen/");

UriComponents encode = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance()
        .scheme("http")
        .host("localhost")
        .path("service/methods")
        .pathSegment("{id}", "{parameters}")
        .buildAndExpand(uriVariables)
        .encode();
System.out.println(encode);
```

*Output*

```
http://localhost/service/methods/5080572115/%2Fhome%2Ffloor%2Fkitchen%2F
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not pretty sure if you understand that is not the correct way to use as`@PathVariable` annotation which indicates that a method parameter should be bound to a `URI` template variable. You need to use `@RequestParam` annotation which indicates that a method parameter should be bound to a web request parameter. Then you might manage by following way: `/home/{id}?parameters=floor,kitchen`
Then your code should see something like this:

```
@GetMapping("/get/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<XXXXX> getXXXXX(@PathVariable id,
                                      @RequestParam List<String> parameters)) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(service.getXXX(id, parameters));
}
```